# Python understanding error

Tags: python, string, if-statement, while-loop

I have been working on a code in which I have to write a program to simulate what happens when mice enter the kitchen when the traps are set and not set, and it should read in multiple lines of input, which describe what happens in the kitchen.

If the line Set the trap. is entered, then the mouse trap becomes baited. If the line Mouse! is entered, the program should print what happens to the mouse. If the trap was set, print out Trap!. If the trap wasn't set, print out The mouse escaped.. For all other lines of input, the program should not do anything. as it should keep reading lines from the user until the user enters a blank line. Once a mouse is caught in the trap, the trap cannot be used to catch another mouse unless it has been reset.

So I have made the program but it's not working for "The mouse escaped". Can anyone please guide me by seeing my code:

```
a = raw_input("Enter line: ")
space = ""
trap_set = True
while a != space:
    a = raw_input("Enter line: ")
    if 'Set the trap.' in a:
        trap_set = True
        print "Trap!"
    else:
        if 'Mouse!' in a:
            trap_set = True
            print "The mouse escaped."
```

I want my program to run like this:

```
Enter line: Go to the fridge.
Enter line: Set the trap.
Enter line: Go to bed.
Enter line: Mouse!
Trap!
Enter line:
```

OR

```
Enter line: Make some dinner.
Enter line: Wash the dishes.
Enter line: Mouse!
The mouse escaped.
Enter line: Sweep the floor.
Enter line: Set the trap.
Enter line: Mouse!
Trap!
Enter line: Go to bed.
Enter line:
```

and this what I am not able to work out.

Comment: You need to describe what is not working: what do you want to happen, and what is happening instead?  (First thing I notice is it is a bit odd that you have the variable `trap_set` but never set it to anything but True.)

Comment: Setting your flag is your main issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of things mixed up here.  If you call 'Mouse!' on the first call, it will fail because you have to set in the conditionals first.

```
a = raw_input("Enter line: ")
space = ""
# did you want to pre-set the trap to True? #
trap_set = False 
while a != space:
    if 'Set the trap.' in a:
        trap_set = True
      # no reason to print trap if just setting #
      #  print "Trap!" #
    elif 'Mouse!' in a: 
        if  trap_set == False:
            print "The mouse escaped."
        elif trap_set == True:
            print 'trap'
            trap_set = False
    a = raw_input("Enter line: ")
```

The last two conditionals are where you are checking to see if the 'trap' was set when your 'mouse' was entered.  Then reset the trap.

Comment: so what you think how should I fix it any hint to get the correct answer?

Comment: run this code, it should do what you want.  if i understand you correctly.  You had to re-set the trap too :)

Comment: I have to edit this to include calling the 'Set the trap.' or 'Mouse!' on the first call.  So you are going to want to put the `raw_input` line last in your `while` loop.

Comment: Ahhh wait one more error when the user input at at first line Mouse! it should print it shoudl ask for another input

Comment: Read the comment above or are you saying you **can't** take in 'Mouse!' with the first line.

Comment: I mean like it should work like this if the user inputs Mouse! at the first place:( Enter line: Mouse!
Enter line: )

Comment: I edited the code above, to print 'mouse escaped' if the first input was 'mouse'.  Did you want the input to repeat without printing anything if the first input was mouse?

Comment: tijko there is a minor error in the situation now! as I put (Enter line: Turn on the radio  Enter line: Sing: Mouse!  Enter line: Turn off the radio  Enter line: ) so can it show me like that?

Comment: beside showing me(Enter line: Turn on the radio, Enter line: Sing: Mouse!, The mouse escaped, Enter line: Turn off the radio Enter line: )

Comment: Are you asking how to make the entry "Sing: Mouse!" not print 'The mouse escaped.'?

Comment: and if the mouse appeared twice so it should print like this (Enter line: set the trap. Enter line: Mouse! Trap! Enter line: Mouse! The mouse escaped. Enter line) I'm terribly confused with this question!!:

Comment: The code above should work for re-setting the trap like you just said.  You should click the check mark next to my answer and post another question if you want to clarify on some other behavior.

Comment: why don't you anwser the question over here! Please

Comment: Could explain a little more clearly what it is that is not right and then how you want the program to behave.

Comment: umm sorry disturb you so much but I want the program to be like:
Enter line: Set the trap.  ,  Enter line: Mouse!, Trap!  , Enter line:Mouse!, Trap!

Comment: " Once a mouse is caught in the trap, the trap cannot be used to catch another mouse unless it has been reset. "  This is a quote from you in your post above.  Did you want the trap to not have to reset now?

Answer (score 2):

I went a slightly different approach to tolo1377 above. I don't care about any input besides '`Set the trap`' and '`Mouse`'.

```
a = raw_input("Enter line: ")
space = ""
trap_set = True
while a != space:
    a = raw_input("Enter line: ")
    if 'Set the trap.' in a:
        trap_set = True
    elif 'Mouse' in a:
        if trap_set:
            print "Mouse trapped!"
            trap_set = False
        else:
            print "The mouse escaped."
```

You weren't doing anything useful in these lines of your program:

```
else:
    if 'Mouse!' in a:
        trap_set = True
        print "The mouse escaped."
```

You are checking if the word '`Mouse`!' appears, which is good, but then you aren't checking if the trap is set or not. You needed to check the trap was set, and then do something if it was.

Comment: Still the same problem! when I wirte like this it doesn't show me:
Enter line: Make some dinner.
Enter line: Wash the dishes.
Enter line: Mouse!
The mouse escaped.

Comment: Umm its means when the trap is not set and when the user input Mous! that should print 'The mouse escaped.'

Comment: So, you did a run where you did not set the trap, and then the mouse appeared, and the mouse escaped. Your description of the problem says: if the user did not set the trap, and the mouse appears, then the mouse should escape. So everything is working exactly like you said you want it to...

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
a = raw_input("Enter line: ")
space = ""
trap_set = True
while a != space:
    if a == 'Set the trap.':
        trap_set = True
    elif a == 'Mouse!' and trap_set == False:
        print "The mouse escaped."
    elif a == 'Mouse!' and trap_set == True:
        print 'Trap!'
        trap_set = False
    a = raw_input("Enter line: ")
```

In your conditions you need to compare the variable to the string literal rather than the other way around.

Also, you want to ask for the the input again at the end because you were not checking the first input. In my solution I also changed trap_set so that it became False once triggered.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `'Set the trap.' in a` should work for seeing if `"Set the trap."` is a substring of `a`, so I don't think that's the main problem.

Comment: yeah its working the main problem is if in user input if I have written 'Set the trap.' then it shouldn't print "Trap!" straight forward first the user should write 'Mouse!' then it should print Trap!

Comment: I don't see what you mean. I ran your example input and it works fine.

Comment: di you tried the second example?? in which its says 
Enter line: Make some dinner.

Enter line: Wash the dishes.

Enter line: Mouse!

The mouse escaped.